# Keras throwing error: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init') and ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'dim_ordering')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I've built the following model with Keras from Tensorflow (version = 2.2.4-tf)

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, padding='same',init='he_normal', input_shape = (target_Width,target_Height, 3),dim_ordering="tf"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dense(18))
```

But somehow I'm getting the following error: `('Keyword argument not understood:', 'init')` and `('Keyword argument not understood:', 'dim_ordering')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use [keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D](https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.1/layers/convolutional/) instead of [tf.keras.layers.Conv2D](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/). If that is the case then use this instead:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D(24, 5, 5, padding='same',init='he_normal', input_shape = (target_Width,target_Height, 3),dim_ordering="tf"))
```

Or using `Conv2D` from `tf.keras` which does not have the arguments `init` and `dim_ordering`:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape = (target_Width,target_Height, 3)))
```

Comment: But `model = tf.keras.Sequential()`, so OP probably uses `tf.keras` (or at least they *should* do so). Mixing `tf.keras` and `keras.layers` (from stand alone Keras) is highly not recommended.

Comment: @desertnaut that is correct I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of these arguments exist, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D).

- By `init`, I take it you meant to use `kernel_initializer`
- `dim_ordering="tf"` is used only in  **stand-alone** Keras (and not in `tf.keras`), as stand-alone Keras can be used with either Tensorflow or Theano backends; these backends use different ordering scheme, hence the need to clarify this. It is not necessary here.

So, here your convolutional layer should be:

```
model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', input_shape = (target_Width,target_Height, 3)))
```

If, as the answer answer suggests, you are indeed using `keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D` from the stand-alone Keras package in a `tf.keras.Sequential()` model, this mixing is **highly not recommended**, and you should revert to `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` instead (and do the same for the rest of the model layers as well).